# Can the descriptions of tag badges be updated to describe the privileges conferred by gold tag badges?

Tags: feature-request, tag-badges

Gold tag badges come with some moderation privileges:

- Gold tag badge holders can unilaterally close questions with the corresponding tag as duplicates of other questions.
- Gold tag badge holders can unilaterally reopen closed-as-duplicate questions with the corresponding tag.
- Gold tag badge holders can edit duplicate links, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqelw.png).

However, these privileges are currently only described in the description of the [Cast Close and Reopen Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege, not in any of the pages describing the tag badges themselves.  Unless they find this page, a user wondering about tag badge privileges must hunt through old meta.se posts like [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212) and [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links)
, or else ask confused meta questions like [I recently did](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8150/what-privileges-exactly-come-with-tag-badges).  This strikes me as a less-than-ideal user experience.

---

The [subsection of the Badges page in the Help Center describing tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) already includes some text specific to tag badges:

> These badges are awarded for participating in **non community-wiki questions** with particular tags. If enough votes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

...and even some text specific to gold tag badges:

> You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

**Can this text be updated to also include a description of the extra moderation privileges that come with holding a gold tag badge?**

Comment: Related: [Add gold tag badge privileges to a user's Privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254765/add-gold-tag-badge-privileges-to-a-users-privileges-page)